# Good algorithm for drawing solid 2-dimensional polygons?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, polygons

What is the simplest (and easiest, although that's subjective) algorithm for drawing solid (as in a single, solid color--no texture mapping) 2D polygons in memory?  What is the most efficient method?

I am not interested in using the GPU or any rendering method, as the output of my program will not be to the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Polygon Fill Teaching Tool](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~icss571/filling/index.html) will show you a very nice, simple algorithm for drawing filled polygons of any complexity.

I've implemented it for embedded graphics, and it's actually a neat (and fun!) algorithm.

-Adam

Comment: More than happy to help!  Care to explain the minor tweak?